# Select a table without tag by Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Could BeautifulSoup select no tag table?
There's many tables in a HTML, but the data I want is in the table without any tags.

Here is my example:
There are 2 tables in HTML.
One is english, and the other is number.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HTML2 = """
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class>a</td>
        <td class>b</td>
        <td class>c</td>
        <td class>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class>e</td>
        <td class>f</td>
        <td class>g</td>
        <td class>h</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class>111</td>
        <td class>222</td>
        <td class>333</td>
        <td class>444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class>555</td>
        <td class>666</td>
        <td class>777</td>
        <td class>888</td>
    </tr>
"""
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(HTML2, 'html.parser')
f2 = soup2.select('table[cellpadding!="0"]') #<---I think the key point is here.
for div in f2:
    row = ''
    rows = div.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows:
        if(row.text.find('td') != False):
            print(row.text)
```

I only want the data in the "english" table
And make the format like following:

```
a b c d
e f g h
```

Then save to excel.

But I can only access that "number" table.
Is there a hint?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) and select only tables that don't have a specific attribute.

```
f2 = soup2.find_all('table', {'cellpadding':None})
```

Or if you want to select tables that have absolutely no attributes:

```
f2 = [tbl for tbl in soup2.find_all('table') if not tbl.attrs]
```

---

Then you can make a list of columns from `f2` and pass it to the dataframe .

```
data = [ 
    [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] 
    for table in f2 for tr in table.find_all('tr') 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **has_attr** method to test whether *table* contains the *cellpadding* attribute:

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(HTML2, 'html.parser')
f2 = soup2.find_all('table')
for div in f2:
    if not div.has_attr('cellpadding'):
        row = ''
        rows = div.findAll('tr')
        for row in rows:
            if(row.text.find('td') != False):
                print(row.text)
```